# Insert data to database row wise when submit button is clicked in php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter for php. I want a table. Data loads perfectly. And I want to enter data to the database when the submit button is clicked. For that, I created a simple form with two inputs for each row that is created on the table. And each row has a submit button. But a problem occurs when I fill the data and click the submit button. I inserted dummy data and the communication between controller and model seems to be fine. When I remove hard coated values, it tries to insert an array to the db table.

This is the error I get : **INSERT INTO `deadlines` (`evaluation_name`, `date`) VALUES (Array, Array)**

Here is my html and php code for the view.

```
<?php                           
foreach($modules as $module)
{                                    
    echo form_open('con_hod_uploads/insertDeadline');      

        echo "<tr>";

            echo "<div class=\"form-group\">";
                echo"<td>";
                    echo "<input type=\"text\" class=\"styleTextBox\" value=\"$module->criteria\" name=\"evaluation_name\" id=\"evaluation_name\" readonly=\"readonly\" ";
                echo"</td>";

                echo"<td>";
                    echo "<input type=\"date\" name=\"dateC\" id=\"dateC\" required=\"required\" ";
                echo"</td>";                                               

                echo "<input type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-primary\" value=\"set\" name=\"set\"/> ";
            echo "</div>";  

        echo "</tr>";

    echo form_close();
}
```

?>

please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: It looks as though you are submitting all the forms values - not just the one you clicked. To see if this is whats happening, in the section that handles the input and saves to the database insert var_dump($_POST);

Comment: Thank you. It seems the case. values are passing from view to controller therefore i used $_POST['evaluation_name'],$_POST['dateC']  to enter the values. its getting inserted to the database now. But i dont know whether this is the correct method to do so or not.

Comment: @M_T add controller code as well

Comment: @Abdulla Here it is.  public function insertDeadline(){
            
            $this->load->model('mod_lectHome');
            
            $data = array(              
                'evaluation_name' => $_POST['evaluation_name'],
                'date' => $_POST['dateC'],
            );
                       
            $this->mod_lectHome->insertDeadlineM($data);
            $this->index();
            
        }

Comment: @M_T Edit your question with controller and Model code

Comment: @Abdulla as i mentioned earlier using $_POST['evaluation_name'], $_POST['dateC'] worked for me. Thank you